# How to get a variable from one window to another in PySide6?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside6

I want to get a variable which usually contains name or simple string variable.The here is that variables only show the value that was set before the gui was launched.

what i want is the updated value input by the user.

here is what i tried.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication, QLineEdit


global text
text = 'unassigned'

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # Adding pages
        self.Homepage = HomeWindow()
        self.new_profile = NewProfile ()
        # Adding to the layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Homepage)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.new_profile)
        # setting the visiblity of the profiles off
        self.new_profile.setVisible(False)

    def setNewVisible(self):
        self.new_profile.setVisible(True)
        self.Homepage.setVisible(False)
        self.Homepage.destroy(True)


class HomeWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setMinimumSize(200,200)
        self.label = QLabel('Type text')
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton('Next')
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.get_text)
      
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def get_text(self):
        global text
        text = self.lineedit.text()
        print(text)
        window.setNewVisible()
        return text


class NewProfile(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel(f'Welcome {text}')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

what should i do to get the name in the next page to become what the user typed?

Comment: You can use Signal and Slot to communicate between two windows